# Activity recalls OnCreate() on phone lock or hangup

Tags: android

I'm locking (hangup) the phone manually when my activity is running. When I unlock my phone, `OnCreate()` is called once again. I'm going with a dialog and webservice hit in OnCreate(). So, when the phone is unlocked another dialog is raised, another webservice hit is called.

Finally what I need is stop calling onCreate() when phone is unlocked. Is there any way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No :)

You cannot stop `onCreate()` from being called. However you can set some flag in `onSaveInstanceState()` which is called before the application is paused. Then in `onCreate()` to read whether the flag is set and know whether the activity has not been created but recreated because of screen lock, app going in background, etc.

Please, check:

[ActivityLifecycle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle)

There it is explained that `onCreate()` might be called multiple times in various situations.

P.S. You cannot also prevent this. Android (and in fact iOS and Windows Phone 7) will pause the application when in background.

Comment: Thank you.This is the way I'm going to do now.Just interested to know whether there is any internal method to stop this.

Comment: The problem may be reproduced if application is started while the screen was locked ...